# I am getting WebDriverException intermittently while invoking deleteAllCookies method in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, cucumber

I have been getting WebDriverException intermittently when control touches deleteAllCookies(). Using selenium manager 4.9.0 version with chrome browser. Please find below exception stacktrace.

```
May 07, 2023 7:19:50 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 112, so returning the closest version found: 111
      org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from no such window
  (Session info: chrome=112.0.5615.86)
Build info: version: '4.8.3', revision: 'e5e76298c3'
System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2019', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.3'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [5992e73ccdeb9a7ba10446065e65b0dc, deleteAllCookies {}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 112.0.5615.86, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 112.0.5615.49 (bd2a7bcb881c..., userDataDir: D:\Users\nshaik\AppData\Loc...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:52051}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:52051/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 112.0.5615.86, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 5992e73ccdeb9a7ba10446065e65b0dc
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:598)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:602)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions.deleteAllCookies(RemoteWebDriver.java:784)
```